# Prevent TreeView from scrolling page down to selected node

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, treeview

I have a TreeView (in UserControl that is placed on SharePoint site) with lots of nodes. After user clicks on any of these nodes PostBack is called and page reloads to the same position (vertically). What I need is to page to be not scrolled to selected node, but stay on its top.
I assume that by default TreeView cannot  do any scroll action, so it could be SharePoint...

here's my code concerning the issue :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {

 if (!IsPostBack)  
 {   
 Load_Tree(); TreeViewDeps.ExpandDepth = 1; }  
 }  

 protected void TreeView_OnSelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
 {  
 Search_TextBox.Text = "";   
LoadList(TreeViewDeps.SelectedNode.Value.ToString(), TreeViewDeps.SelectedNode.Text);    
}
```

Comment: can you not just set the nodes SelectedIndex at that point within the postback by storing it's value in a Session also to be clear on what you are saying.. are you saying that you  want it to not be on the last Selected Node after `PostBack` can you show your `Page_Load` code as well as the Selected_Node EventHandler

Comment: <code>protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Load_Tree();
                TreeViewDeps.ExpandDepth = 1;
            }
        }

protected void TreeView_OnSelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Search_TextBox.Text = "";
            LoadList(TreeViewDeps.SelectedNode.Value.ToString(), TreeViewDeps.SelectedNode.Text);
        }
</code>

here's my code concerning the issue

Comment: word of advise when adding code add it to your original Question. Edit and post it there its too hard to read in the comments section